# OpenGL Texture - texture render twice

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a problem that a texture covers only part of an object in height dimensions and start over again rendering a smaller texture in the bottom as shown in the pic.

[image: problem noted in red]

I'm posting my Texture and Shader code as well. note that I'm using `glTexSubImage2D` for the background of the object. the same problem occurred when I didn't use the `glTexSubImage2D` and just `glTexImage2D`.

**texture code**

```
try {

    data = stbi_load((fileName).c_str(), &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);

    if (data == NULL)
        std::cerr << "Unable to load texture: " << fileName << std::endl;
    else
        std::cerr << "texture loaded " << fileName << std::endl;
    std::string fileName2 = t ? filePathe + "//images//" + mediaColor + ".bmp" : "./res/textures/plane1.bmp";
    int width2, height2, numComponents2;
    unsigned char* data2 = stbi_load((fileName2).c_str(), &width2, &height2, &numComponents2, 4);
    if (data2 == NULL)
        std::cerr << "Unable to load texture: " << fileName2 << std::endl;
    else
        std::cerr << "texture loaded " << fileName2 << std::endl;
    glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width2, height2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data2);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height , GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    stbi_image_free(data);
    stbi_image_free(data2);
}
catch (std::invalid_argument &e)
{
```

---

**vertex shader**

```
#version 120

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec3 color;

varying vec2 texCoord0;
varying vec3 normal0;
varying vec3 color0;
varying float index0;

uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat4 Normal;

uniform float index;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(position, 1.0);

    texCoord0 = texCoord;
    if (index == 0.0) {
        //texCoord0[0]=0.25+texCoord0[0];
        texCoord0[1]=1-texCoord0[1];
    }

}
```

---

**fragment shader**

```
#version 130

varying vec2 texCoord0;
varying vec3 normal0;
varying vec3 color0;
varying float index0;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture1;  // added

uniform vec3 lightDirection;
uniform vec3 capOffSet;
uniform vec3 mediaColor;
uniform vec3 capColor;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture(ourTexture1, texCoord0);
}
```

Comment: I'd say that looks like your texture coordinates just go beyond 1.0 and the texture, thus, wraps around (you even set up the wrapping mode yourself)!?

Comment: What did you expect to happen to the not-covered part? As @MichaelKenzel said, you set up the texture wrapping mode to `GL_REPEAT`

Comment: OK i see your point i did try diffrent command then the:  "glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT) " 
I want the texture will cover all the tube (i prefer to control the height and the width )with no repetition. is there a way that i can do that?

Comment: @דודוינר: that's a matter of where your texture coordinates come from